# Basic Coke Logos not recognized in the distance

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I cannot get Google Vision to detect Coke logos where they are less than 10% of the screen. Logo is approximately 200x30 but it is still pretty clearly discernible to a human eye. Visa logo next to it is a bit bigger and cannot be detected as well.

Anyone knows what is the minimum size for logo detection? These ones are easily recognized by mxnet.

I am using the regular sample code to detect it:

```
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

with io.open("tmp/"+filename, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()

image = vision.types.Image(content=content)

response = client.logo_detection(image=image)
logos = response.logo_annotations
print('Logos:')

for logo in logos:
    print(logo.description)
```

here is a sample image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYlad.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The [recommended image size for logo detection](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files#image_sizing) is 640 x 480 pixels. Google Vision API's accuracy might vary for the given image quality. For your case, the quality of the actual logos in your image seems to be low for logo detection.